# HAProxy Ingress controller : Startup Probe failing <ip>/healthz

Tags: kubernetes, haproxy, haproxy-ingress

I have deployed a Kubernetes cluster on digital ocean droplet (using kubeadm).
I installed HAProxy using helm chart (as suggested in their blog https://www.haproxy.com/blog/use-helm-to-install-the-haproxy-kubernetes-ingress-controller/)

```
helm install haproxy haproxytech/kubernetes-ingress \
  --set controller.kind=DaemonSet
  --set controller.daemonset.useHostPort=true
  --set controller.daemonset.useHostNetwork=true
  --set controller.service.type=LoadBalancer
  --set-string "controller.config.ssl-redirect=true"
```

I have pointed my ingress to the HAProxy by setting the Ingress class to "haproxy"

```
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ****-ingress
  annotations:
    # nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: haproxy
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: ****-issuer
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
     - <my-custom-domain>
    secretName: *****
  rules:
  - host: <my-custom-domain>
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service: 
            name: frontend
            port:
              number: 80
      - path: /api
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service: 
            name: backend
            port:
              number: 8000
```

The issue is haproxy loadbalancer is taking forever to create an external ip
The only errors that I found from the pods are :

[image]

[image]

What is going wrong here ?!
Thanks in advance !

Comment: you have installed this ? : https://github.com/digitalocean/digitalocean-cloud-controller-manager

Comment: Nope, I haven't. Is that useful for the current scenario ? @HarshManvar

Comment: i think this is answer of your question : https://github.com/digitalocean/digitalocean-cloud-controller-manager/tree/master/docs/controllers/services/examples#load-balancers